# I cannot see case object in object setting in a Permission set?

Tags: case, permissions

[image]

Can anyone help to add Case to my object settings?
Thanks in advance

Solution : Thank you for the answers. I figured that at some point I have changed the label of Case object.

Comment: Please check if your user is not having access to Case object from profile or if the Case Tab is disabled?

Comment: I can see that the screenshot is showing until "Card Payment Methods" Object only and the "Cases" Object should be there after this Object.I would suggest you to search using the name to find out easily.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I figured that at some point I have changed the label of Case object.